# C forks, kill the parent after returning its PID

Tags: c, fork

I'm new to C and I've been investigating about forks the last two weeks, I have to solve this problem for my Operative Systems class:

"You must create a "heavy weight" process using a fork, then the first process must wait for the second (the new one) to return its parent id, then it must kill its parent and finish"

I think the instructions are quite confusing, this is my code so far ( As I said, I'm new to C so I've been just investigating) 
My problem seems to be that the parent is not even waiting for the child process to return its id, because after that, the child is killing the parent, so I think I'm creating the child process, and when it runs it kills the parent at the end, not letting the parent to wait for the child execution. (that's the part I think is confusing about the instructions)
I want to know more about forks and processes, like the logic behind them so I can feel more sure when coding.
Thanks!

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    pid_t idProceso;
    int childState;

    idProceso = fork();

    if (idProceso == 0){
        printf ("child id  :  %d. parent id %d\n", 
        getpid(), getppid());

            int parent = getppid();
            kill(parent, SIGKILL);
            printf ("dead parent"); //  not sure about it  ??
            _exit();
    }

    if(idProceso > 0){
        sleep (1);
        printf ("parent id :  %d. child id %d\n", 
        getpid(), idProceso);

        wait (&childState);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To be honest, that sentence - even after reading twice - does not make any sense to me. In all cases I can think of the process being killed already exited.

Comment: I don't understand what you're supposed to do, but the reason the parent isn't waiting is because it starts the `sleep`, but the child is set to kill it immediately, so does so.

Comment: You both are right, I mean, I think the sentence is confusing, but that's the way the teacher gave it to us. It's like:
-create a process
-create a child process
-the parent waits for the child
-the child kills the parent (this is the part I'm confused) and it finishes

Answer (score 1):

Based on the assignment description you gave, I think the instructor or professor who assigned it does not have a good handle on either the English language or the concept of processes on a Unix machine.

The solution you presented is reasonable, but I would I remove the call to sleep. Childstate is never set correct, and you don't need it all. Additionally, don't send SIGKILL to the parent. SIGKILL is the last way to attempt to terminate a process. I suggest sending SIGTERM to the parent process. The parent process can install a signal handler with sigaction if you are using a Linux machine. In the signal handler, you can print a nice message like "Received terminate signal from child" and call exit. If you do this your professor will probably be suitably impressed with your skills to give you a passing grade.

Failing that, I would ask for a better problem. It was not uncommon for me to have to submit grammatical and punctuation corrections to professors for approval before actually solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem seems to be that the parent is not even waiting for the
>   child process to return its id

Nowhere in your program is the child returning its id to the parent. The only comunication that is happening is the child sending a SIGKILL signal to the parent.

> so I think I'm creating the child process, and when it runs it kills
>   the parent at the end, not letting the parent to wait for the child
>   execution.

Yes , you are right , the child will kill the parent process , by sending a SIGKILL signal , using the kill() function , but the parent actually waits to get killed by the child.

```
wait (&childState);
```

This here makes the parent wait(hang there) for the child to terminate , after termination , the parent will move on , but in your program , while the parent waits for the child to get terminated , the child itself will terminate the parent during the wait.

> I want to know more about forks and processes, like the logic behind
>   them so I can feel more sure when coding.

This is [something](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html) worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ./foo.bin
parent id :  6629. child id 6630
child id  :  6630. parent id 6629
dead parentKilled
```

I just removed the `sleep(1)` and the output seems to be reasonable.

Comment: yes that's the same result I'm receiving so far, the only thing I want to be sure about is if the parent is actually waiting (I put a printf before and after the wait() but none of them is being printed)

Comment: `parent id : ..... child id ...` comes from the `parent` process and there is no sane reason why the `parent` process should stop at that. So it is stuck at wait. But if your really want go to level below, use a debugger or call tracer.